# Is there a way to define variables usable in all subtests in node tap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, tap

I was wondering if there's a way to declare a variable before all the subtests in node tap js in order to use it in each one of them. Something like this:

```
      tap.test('...', async (t) => {
         
        t.before(async () => {
           const myVariable = ...
        }

        t.test('SubTest 1', async (t) => {
           await someMethod(myVariable)
        }

        t.test('SubTest 2', async (t) => {
           await someMethod(myVariable)
        }
      }
```

It can be achieved another way, the idea is that I'd like to initialize some variables that I'll be using through all the subtests.

Comment: you declared the variable in the block.... it is only assessable in that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the variable declaration where the others can read it.

```js
tap.test('...', async (t) => {
  let myVariable;
  t.before(async () => {
    myVariable = '';
  }
});
```